# How to filter an object array by a string with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, jquery-select2

This is how my object array looks like:

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"John"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Jose"},
  {"id":"3", "name":"Mike"}
]
```

I want to filter it with a String like "jo" so it can bring me first and second item.

How can make it return the Objects in the same "object array" form such as this:

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"John"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Jose"}
]
```

The object filtered on an autocomplete dropdown menu created by "select2.js" library.

This is what I create using the examples in stackoverflow so far:

("something to do" part is where I have failed, other parts work well)

```
$parameterSelect.select2({
    data : {
        results : $scope.parameters,
        text : 'name'
    },
// init selected from elements value
initSelection    : function (element, callback) {
    var initialData = [];

    $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
        initialData.push({
            id  : this,
            text: this
        });
    });
    callback(initialData);
},
formatSelection : formatFunction,
formatResult : formatFunction,
multiple : true,
formatLoadMore   : 'Loading more...',
placeholder : "Select parameters",
// query with pagination
query            : function (q) {
    var pageSize,
    results;
    pageSize = 20; // or whatever pagesize
    results  = [];
    if (q.term && q.term !== "") {
    // HEADS UP; for the _.filter function i use underscore (actually lo-dash) here
       results = _.filter(this.data, function (e) {
            //something to do
       });
    } else if (q.term === "") {
        results = this.data;
    }
    q.callback({
        results: results.results.slice((q.page - 1) * pageSize, q.page * pageSize),
        more   : results.results.length >= q.page * pageSize
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter with a function which tests a regexp against the name property of each element.

```
_.filter(array, function(elt) { return /jo/i.test(elt.name); })
```

Comment: ... or just `elt.name.includes('jo')`.

Comment: Yes, for case-insensitive regex test is the way to go. )

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand the syntax here. Why is the search string between two slashes (/jo/) ?

Comment: It's a regular expression.

Comment: @raina77ow inside the function "elt" is just equal to "array" so "elt.name" is undefined. There is a value when it is "elt[0].name". But I don't know exactly how to loop through.

Comment: @torazaburo I quickly write the comment before understanding it. There is one more thing I cannot understand in the function: "elt.name" is undefined because it is somehow equal to "array". However, when it is "elt[0].name" it gives some value. How can I make "elt" to be one of "array"s elements?

Comment: `elt` is not the array; it is each element (object) in the array. Read the docs for `_.filter` and its `predicate` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own matcher for select2:

https://select2.github.io/options.html

```
matcher: function (params, data) {
  // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
  if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
    return data;
  }

  // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
  // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
  if (data.name.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
    var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);

    // You can return modified objects from here
    // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
    return modifiedData;
  }

  // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
  return null;
}
```